# How to send a notification after checking ModelValidation in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I want user to fill the form and after filling it, if the form is compatible with Validations(there can't be a null value) I want to show user a "Successfull" notification. But in this code, when I click on save button , it doesn't check the validations even though I didn't fill the form but still pushes "Successfull" notification. How can check the validations in Javascript. What am I missing here because I'm terrible at Javascript?

```
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
 
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css  />
    <script defer src="~/js/site.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" asp-action="Create" id="form" >
        
    <div class="form-group">

    <label asp-for="Order">Order</label>
    <input asp-for="Order" class="form-control"  id="Order" >
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Order,"")
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Order" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    </br>

    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">
         <p1>Save</p1>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" style="visibility:visible" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1"> Button</button>

    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="Modal1" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        New product has been saved successfully.
                    </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
       
        $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                
                //function checkFormValidateOrNot() {

                //    if ($(".field-validation-error").length > 0) {
                //        return false;
                //    }

                //    $(".form-control").each(function () {
                //        if ($(this).attr("data-val") == "true" && $(this).val() == "" &&
                //            $(this).is("select") == false) {
                //            return false;
                //        }
                //    });

                //    return true;
                //}

                $("#btnSave").click(function () {
                    
                    //if (checkValidateOrNot() == true) {

                    //}
                       $('#Modal1').modal('show');
                });
              
            })
            
        })
    
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Hi @vives, any update here?

Answer (score 0):

1.You can use `validate()` method which exists in `jquery.validate.js` to validate the form.

2.It is better for you to use the default version bootstrap and jquery in wwwroot folder. Otherwise, the modal will not display due to the compatibility of the nuget packages.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

Whole working demo:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>     
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css  />
    <script defer src="~/js/site.js"></script>

              //modify here...
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>       
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" asp-action="Create" id="form" >            
    <div class="form-group">    
    <label asp-for="Order">Order</label>
    <input asp-for="Order" class="form-control"  id="Order" >
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.Order,"")
            <span asp-validation-for="@Model.Order" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>    
    </br>    
    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">
         <p1>Save</p1>
    </div>
    <div class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSave">
    <button  class="btn btn-primary" style="visibility:visible" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Modal1"> Button</button>    
    </div>
    </form>
    <div id="Modal1" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        New product has been saved successfully.
                    </div>   
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
       
        $(function () {
            $(document).ready(function () {               
                $("#btnSave").click(function () {    
                    var validator = $("#form").validate();
                    var flag = validator.form();
                    if (flag) {
                        $('#Modal1').modal('show');
                     }                         
                });                  
            })                
        })      
    </script>
</body>
```